# Avoid using multiple if else php

Tags: php, codeigniter

Is there any way to avoid using multiple if else? I have this method:

```
//Answer Question
public function answer()
{

    //Validate form input
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('question_id', '', 'integer|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('answer_text', 'lang:answer_text', 'trim|required|xss_clean');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == true) 
    {
        $question_exists = $this->questions->select_by_id($this->input->post('question_id'), 1);

        //Check if question exists
        if($question_exists) {

            //Add to database
            $answer_id = $this->answers->create(
                array(
                    'question_id'    => $this->input->post('question_id'),
                    'answer_text'    => $this->input->post('answer_text'),
                    'commentator_id' => ($this->ion_auth->logged_in()) ? $this->the_user->id : 0,
                    'answer_date'    => time()
                )
            );

            if ($answer_id) 
            {
                $data['answer'] = $this->answers->select_by_id($answer_id);

                if($this->ion_auth->logged_in()) 
                    $this->users->update(array('answers' => $this->the_user->answers + 1), $this->the_user->id);
                //check if answer is posted on a category page or profile page
                if ($question_exists->asked_id != 0) {
                    $this->questions->update(array('question_status' => 1), $question_exists->question_id);
                    $data['answer_profile'] = true;
                } else {
                    $data['answer_profile'] = false;
                }

                $this->load->view('blocks/new_answer', $data);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you see I have a lot of if else and braces. Is there any possibility to optimize the code to be more organised?

Comment: You could split things out into other methods. You could also reverse some of your conditionals and `return` out of them, thereby skipping execution of subsequent code (which won't reduce the number, but will prevent nesting).

Answer (score 2):

Merely a suggestion, since I don't know your code context.

I do prefer to use private methods to shorten public ones.

(Please, be aware for any reference mistakes)

```
//Answer Question
public function answer()
{

    //Validate form input
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('question_id', '', 'integer|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('answer_text', 'lang:answer_text', 'trim|required|xss_clean');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() && $this->questionExists())
    {
        $question_exists = $this->questionExists();
        //Add to database
        $answer_id = $this->addQuestion();
        $answer_id ? $data['answer'] = $this->answers->select_by_id($answer_id) : return;

        if($this->ion_auth->logged_in()) 
            $this->users->update(array('answers' => $this->the_user->answers + 1), $this->the_user->id);

        //check if answer is posted on a category page or profile page
        $question_exists->asked_id != 0 ? $this->updateAnswer() : $data['answer_profile'] = false;

        $this->load->view('blocks/new_answer', $data);
    }
}

private function questionExists()
{
    return $this->questions->select_by_id($this->input->post('question_id'), 1);
}

private function addQuestion()
{
    $a_id = $this->answers->create(
                array(
                    'question_id'    => $this->input->post('question_id'),
                    'answer_text'    => $this->input->post('answer_text'),
                    'commentator_id' => ($this->ion_auth->logged_in()) ? $this->the_user->id : 0,
                    'answer_date'    => time()
                )
            );
    return $a_id;
}

private function updateAnswer() {
    $this->questions->update(array('question_status' => 1), $question_exists->question_id);
    $data['answer_profile'] = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An attempt by me, but without understanding the full scope...

```
    public function answer()
{

    //Validate form input
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('question_id', '', 'integer|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('answer_text', 'lang:answer_text', 'trim|required|xss_clean');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == true)
    {
       //just insert instead of getting/checking if exists, i'm assuming it does, since you are passing what appears to be a primary key of a question
        $answer = array(
            'question_id'    => $this->input->post('question_id'),
            'answer_text'    => $this->input->post('answer_text'),
            'commentator_id' => $this->input->post('user_id'), // instead of checking if the users logged on, we add it to a field in the form before hand, user_id if so, 0 otherwise
            'answer_date'    => time()
        );
        if($answer_id = $this->answers->create($answer)){
            $data['answer'] = $this->answers->select_by_id($answer_id);
            $this->users->update(array('answers' => $this->the_user->answers + 1), $this->input->post('user_id')); //check in method update, if user_id == 0, return immediately
            $this->questions->update(array('question_status' => 1), $this->input->post('question_id')); //update where qestion id == $this->input->post('question_id') && `asked_column` != 0
            $data['answer_profile'] = $this->questions->check_if_asked($this->input->post('question_id'));//method to determine if asked, if this != 0, return true, in the view we can use isset
            $this->load->view('blocks/new_answer', $data);
        }
     }
}
```